# Insert data with GET in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, get

I want insert data in table "test" but I have problem when insert data in mysql
my database name mytesttable

that code insert data with GET :

```
<?php
include_once('confi.php');

echo "hi there this is a test";
//Get the variables here
$username= isset($_GET['username']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']) :  "";
$email = isset($_GET['email']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']) :  "";
$password = isset($_GET['password']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password']) :  "";
$insertstatement = 'INSERT INTO `test`(`id`,`username`,`email`,`password`) VAlUES (NULL,"'.$username.'","'.$email.'","'.$password.'")';

$query123 = mysql_query($insertstatement) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$insertstatement);

echo "$query123";


?>
```

this my code connect with MySQL :

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'); ?>
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT'); ?>

<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","mytesttable","8889");

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Error occured while connecting with database ".mysqli_connect_errno();
    }


?>
```

what is problem in my code ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You can't mix mysql and mysqli methods.

Comment: @aynber can you tell me how I can solve that please ?

Comment: Use mysqli functions for everything instead of mysql. I'd strongly urge you to take advantage of mysqli's prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Use [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

```
<?php
include_once('confi.php');

$username= isset($_GET['username']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']) :  "";
$email = isset($_GET['email']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']) :  "";
$password = isset($_GET['password']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password']) :  "";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO `test`(`username`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $username, $email, $password);

$query123 = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

?>
```

Learn [Prepared Statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

[**NOTE:** [Mysql is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) ]